# How do I close "TIME_WAIT"?

Tags: apache, tcp

when i exec "netstat -tanp" on apache server, there are many TIME_WAIT.
apache server is under loadbalancer (i use snat).

TIME_WAIT was over 3000 remain.
i couldn't figure out why the tcp_connection couldn't close.

i tried some settings.

sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
```

apache

```
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

but it had no effect.

i need to know the TCP State Transition and want to solve the problem.

are there any good tool or command to know what is happend.

OS:Centos6.9

thanks.

Comment: [The Transmission Control Protocol Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) should give you part of what you want. And it might not *need* to be "solved". It depends on the options of the sockets, if the `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_LINGER` options. But for disposable sockets it's often not needed at all, since they sooner or later will finish the `TIME_WAIT` state by themselves.

Comment: Also note that turning off keep-alive might make things *worse* for you, as now the connections needs one socket per request, instead of reusing existing connections. That means *more* sockets used and possibly in the `TIME_WAIT` state, not less.

Comment: thanks. this apache server receives many connections (1k～3k req/min). when i setted "KeepAlive ON" , over cpu load happend.  it had been no troubule in this few years with keepalive off. one day, time_wait increased suddenly...

Comment: It *did* close. The TIME_WAIT state comes *after* the close. It will disappear in two minutes in each case. You need to ensure that *HTTP* keepalive is enabled.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It has exactly nothing to do wih either SO_REUSEADDR or SO_LINGER, unless the latter has been abused.